# Python requests.get in for loop returning 301 when more than one url

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I would like to get some content from web pages automatically so I have collected a file of urls that I wish to get from then use xpath to collect information. However, if I have more then one url in the file the first request I do returns a 301, if there is only one url then I get a 200 and the find commands work. I have looked but around but nothing seems to be coming up. Why is this happening?

```
from lxml import html, etree
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

content = open(pathToURLs).readlines()


for url in content:
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
```

Comment: try debugging by printing the url in the for loop. Check whether it is the complete url which is being searched or not.

Comment: Thank you!!! It had a newline character in it